# Creating a class inside a function

Tags: javascript, html

I have this part in the HTML file to get the email and password from a new user and create a new profile:

```
<form name="userInfo"> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create a new account</legend> 

        <div>
            <label>Email:</label>   
            <input type="email" name="userEmail" required="required" /> 
        </div> 

        <div>
            <label>Password:</label>    
            <input type="password" name="userPass" required="required" /> 
        </div> 

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

Now, I want to take both the email and the password to create a profile. The profile class needs to take both as arguments/parameters:

```
function profile(email, password){
    this.email = email; 
    this.pass = password; 
}

function createProfile(event){
    email = event.target["userEmail"].value; 
    password = event.target["userPass"].value; 
    var newProfile = profile(email, password);  
}

var email; 
var password; 
document.forms["userInfo"].addEventListener("submit", createProfile);
```

Of course, the newly created profile would be wiped from the memory once the function 'createProfile' terminated. In C, we used to go around this by using malloc, calloc or whatnot which is not present in JS; what is the most straight forward approach I need to follow here?

Comment: Return the value and use it somewhere. `window.profile = createProfile(event);`. And for the record, I think global variables are bad.

Comment: there's a distinct lack of `new` keyword in the code

Comment: Objects in JavaScript with a reference never disappear....  There is no comparison to C memory.

Comment: Also, it would be `new profile(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of jQuery serialise/serialise array which sends all the formdata on submit

```js
$(function(){
  $( ".userInfo" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
 var result=$( this ).serialize().split('&');
    alert(result)
    alert(result.length)
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="userInfo"> 
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Create a new account</legend> 

        <div>
            <label>Email:</label>   
            <input type="email" name="userEmail" required="required" /> 
        </div> 

        <div>
            <label>Password:</label>    
            <input type="password" name="userPass" required="required" /> 
        </div> 

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /> 
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Rob, you should return the profile object from createProfile() and also, it's a bad thing keep those variable as global.

You could try something like this

```
function createProfile(event){
  var profile = {};//Empty object

  profile.Email = event.target["userEmail"].value; 
  profile.Password = event.target["userPass"].value; 

  return profile;
}

var newProfile = createProfile(eventFired);//Here you will have your profile object to be posted
```

For this approach, jquery isn't necessary but it's a good option too.